# Closing ears while making adhan(call to prayer)

Tags: adab, adhan

Is it necessary to close the ears with fingers while making adhan(call to prayer)?

I have one more question on this topic.

What about turning the head right and left when saying `hayyaa alas salah` and `falah`?

Please provide some references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullahi wa baraktuh,

Narrated Awn Ibn Abu Juhaifa

> "My father said, I saw Bilal turning his face from side to side while
>   pronouncing the Adhan for the prayer."

[Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/31)

> "I saw the movement of his mouth from this side to that side upon
>   saying "Hayya 'alas-salah" and "Hayya 'alal-falah."

[Musnad Ahmad]

> "I saw Bilal calling the Adhan, and turning, and his (face) was
>   following here and there, and his (index) fingers were in his ears"

[Jami at-Tirmidhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/49)

It is Sunnah to turn slightly to the right upon declaring ‘Hayya alas-Salaah’ and to the left upon declaring ‘Hayya alal-Falaah’ during the adhan and the iqamah; but if for any reason one forgets or does not do so, the ‘Adhan’ will still be valid.

And Allah alone knows best

Wa assalam

Comment: nice answer but only a part of the question is answered

Comment: @Ashu - Which part was not answered?

Comment: +1, pls add answer about closing the ears during adhan

Comment: @Muslim - The answer would be the same as the 'turning'. It is a Sunnah but not fard (as it's not stated anywhere that it is a must). And Allah knows best. May Allah grant you goodness, ameen.